# plotting two subgraphs together

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

I have a graph G that contains a set of nodes stored in `nodeNames` and I have two subgraphs A and B of G as follows : it just a partition of a longer code

```
    G = digraph(adj,nodeNames);
    h = plot(G);
    v = dfsearch(G,'n');
    disp(v);                             % v is a cell array that contains all the nodes are included in the path of n 
    A=subgraph(G,v);           % the first subgraph that contains the nodes that are included in the path of n 
    NoNodeAccess=setdiff(nodeNames,v);   % NoNodeAccess is a cell array that includes all the remaining nodes that are not in the path of n
    B=subgraph(G,NoNodeAccess);  % the second subgraph.
```

Now i want a plot that contains both of the subgraph and i want to distinguish between them by linetype or if possible circle every subgraph alone . how to do that ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

this command can help to generate the new plot while holding the old plot:

```
hold on
```

you can add this command between generating two figures. basically new plot will have a different color to distinguish from the previous one, and you can definitely use plot property to change the line type and color as well.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html